# Yocto complains about two recipes installing the same header file

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

When building an image using `bitbake`, the build complains about how this particular header file (under `/usr/include` == kernel header file?) is being installed by both the recipes.

```
./tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/glibc/2.27-r0/temp/log.do_prepare_recipe_sysroot.21803:807:DEBUG: Removing manifest: /repo/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/glibc/2.27-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/scsi/scsi_ioctl.h

ERROR: glibc-2.27-r0 do_prepare_recipe_sysroot: The file /usr/include/scsi/scsi_ioctl.h is installed by both linux-libc-headers and glibc-initial, aborting

ERROR: glibc-2.27-r0 do_prepare_recipe_sysroot: Function failed: extend_recipe_sysroot

/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/glibc/2.27-r0/temp/log.do_prepare_recipe_sysroot.16343:976:Exception: FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/repo/build/tmp/sysroots-components/aarch64/linux-libc-headers/usr/include/scsi/scsi_ioctl.h' -> 'repo/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/glibc/2.27-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/scsi/scsi_ioctl.h'
```

**Observation**

I first looked for `scsi_ioctl.h` inside the `source` directory...to no avail.

Then, I tried looking into the respective recipe files both of which require the `.inc` file so I opened that instead.

- I see `glibc-initial` depends on `linux-libc-headers`, which merely means (according to my understanding) that `bitbake` builds `linux-libc-headers` first prior to `glibc-initial`.
- `linux-libc-headers` removes the `scsi.h`. (Not sure if it's related to the current header it's complaining about)
- I also see a long note in `linux-libc-headers.inc` that talks about how you do not have to add `libc` custom extensions to the kernel. In addition, it says if you need to use kernel drivers, get them from `STAGING_KERNEL_DIR`, which is set in `bitbake.conf` to `"${TMPDIR}/work-shared/${MACHINE}/kernel-source"`, and I already see `scsi_ioctl.h` is located there.

```
// glibc-initial.inc
DEPENDS = "linux-libc-headers virtual/${TARGET_PREFIX}gcc-initial libgcc-initial"
PROVIDES = "virtual/${TARGET_PREFIX}libc-initial"

....
do_install () {
        oe_runmake cross-compiling=yes install_root=${D} \
        includedir='${includedir}' prefix='${prefix}' \
        install-bootstrap-headers=yes install-headers

        oe_runmake csu/subdir_lib
        mkdir -p ${D}${libdir}/
        install -m 644 csu/crt[1in].o ${D}${libdir}
```

```
// linux-libc-headers.inc 
do_install() {
        oe_runmake headers_install INSTALL_HDR_PATH=${D}${exec_prefix}
        # Kernel should not be exporting this header
        rm -f ${D}${exec_prefix}/include/scsi/scsi.h

        # The ..install.cmd conflicts between various configure runs
        find ${D}${includedir} -name ..install.cmd | xargs rm -f
}

#########################################################################
####                        PLEASE READ
#########################################################################
#
# You're probably looking here thinking you need to create some new copy
# of linux-libc-headers since you have your own custom kernel. To put
# this simply, you DO NOT.
#
# Why? These headers are used to build the libc. If you customise the
# headers you are customising the libc and the libc becomes machine
# specific. Most people do not add custom libc extensions to the kernel
# and have a machine specific libc.
#
# But you have some kernel headers you need for some driver? That is fine
# but get them from STAGING_KERNEL_DIR where the kernel installs itself.
# This will make the package using them machine specific but this is much
# better than having a machine specific C library. This does mean your
# recipe needs a
#    do_configure[depends] += "virtual/kernel:do_shared_workdir"
# but again, that is fine and makes total sense.
#
# There can also be a case where your kernel extremely old and you want
# an older libc ABI for that old kernel. The headers installed by this
# recipe should still be a standard mainline kernel, not your own custom
# one.
```

**Question/Concern**

- if the recipes themselves aren't installing the header file, who else may be? I am missing out on the point but that's because I'm still new to yocto and trying to figure things out.
- Shouldn't yocto be looking into the `build/tmp/work/<machine-name>` and not `build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux`, where `<machine-name>` is whatever it's set to in `build/conf/local.conf` file, which isn't `aarch64`

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Please specify what version of yocto (gatesgarth etc) you are using.

As glibc is a very common package, I assume something has gotten messed up with your yocto `tmp` directory rather than a problem with yocto itself. (In my dunfell build, `scsi_ioctl.h` appears only under the glibc recipe.) Current yocto builds a distinct sysroot for each package, but in earlier versions used a common sysroot and it was rather fragile.

You can try:

```
bitbake -c cleanall glibc
bitbake -c cleanall linux-libc-headers
```

then rebuild. If that doesn't work, you can try the nuclear option of renaming `tmp` to some other name and re-running your build. If you've been using the same `tmp` through more than one yocto version or more than one kernel recipe, I definitely recommend a fresh start.

Re: `tmp/work/<machine>` vs `tmp/work/<arch>`; yocto tries to reuse build products as widely as possible.  If a package is machine-specific (e.g. the kernel and device tree) it gets built under `tmp/work/<machine>`. If it is architecture-specific (e.g. compiled C code) but not machine-specific, it gets built under `tmp/work/<arch>`. A few packages (e.g. `ca-certificates`) are platform-independent, and are built in a `tmp/work/<all>` directory.

We build for several different Cortex A8 machines; most packages end up in `tmp/work/coretexta8hf-neon-linux-gnueabi` but a handful of packages have machine-specific overrides and end up in the machine-specific directories.